# .htaccess rewrite rule to redirect all pages from one domain to another EXCEPT for one specific URL?

Tags: .htaccess

I've looked through at least 50 different questions and posts on here on this topic, and tried everything and anything and still can't figure out how to do this.

I need to redirect all pages/URLs from domain1.com to domain2.com EXCEPT FOR a specific URL like domain1.com/paypal/ipn (to prevent Paypal IPN notifications from being broken... long story).

How do I pull that off/write that in terms of RewriteRules and RewriteConds...?

I've literally tried everything and I can easily get the domain1.com to domain2.com redirect:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But that other requirement, to ignore and skip a specific URL from ever being redirected in any way, nothing works so far...

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude a specific page from the redirection you could use the following :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/paypal/ipn [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If there are multiple pages or URIs to exclude, you can either use `RewriteCond` with OR flag or use a regex based pattern in the rule

Multiple conditions :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/paypal/ipn [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/foo/bar [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Regex based pattern :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !(page1|page2) https://www.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this new 301 reditect.